Google Sign-In Error: "Unable to process request due to missing initial state"
I'm encountering an issue with Google Sign-In in my React application using Firebase Auth. Everything was working fine until June 24, 2024, but now I get the following error when trying to sign in:

Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment.

Here is the code I am using for the sign-in process:
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' })

    try {
      const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      const user = result.user
      const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
      const userDocByEmail = await usersRef.where('mail', '==', user.email).get()
      const newDocExistingAccount = firebase.firestore().collection('existingAccounts').doc().id

      if (!userDocByEmail.empty) {
        const existingUserRef = userDocByEmail.docs[0].ref
        await existingUserRef.update({ 'metadata.last_login': new Date() })
        const existingUserDoc = await existingUserRef.get()
        resolve({ user: existingUserDoc.data(), isNewUser: false, success: true, message: 'Successfully signed in with Google.' })
      } else {
        const userRef = usersRef.doc(user.uid)
        await userRef.set({
          mail: user.email,
          first_name: user.displayName.split(' ')[0],
          last_name: user.displayName.split(' ')[1] || '',
          compagny: '',
          user_id: user.uid,
          role: 'Client',
          country: null,
          personalPhone: null,
          metadata: {
            status: 'PendingRegistration',
            last_login: new Date(),
            registration_date: new Date()
          },
          emailVerfied: user.emailVerified
        })

        await firebase.firestore().collection('existingAccounts').doc(newDocExistingAccount)
          .set({ mail: user.email, mail_id: newDocExistingAccount, user_id: user.uid, created_on: new Date().toISOString() })

        const newUserDoc = await userRef.get()
        resolve({
          user: newUserDoc.data(),
          isNewUser: true,
          success: true,
          message: `Your account is currently under validation. However, you are free to explore and use our platform at your convenience. Thank you for your understanding.`
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      let errorMessage = 'An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.'
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
          errorMessage = `Sorry, no user found with the provided login information. Please check your details and try again.`
          break
        case 'auth/email-already-exists':
          errorMessage = `The email address you entered is already associated with an existing account. If this email address belongs to you, please sign in through the login page. If you don't remember your password, you can reset it by following the recovery instructions on our login page.`
          break
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
          errorMessage = `The provided email address is not valid. Please check your information and try again.`
          break
        case 'auth/wrong-password':
          errorMessage = 'The provided password is incorrect. Please check your details and try again.'
          break
        case 'auth/user-disabled':
          errorMessage = `Your account has been disabled. Please contact our support team for more information.`
          break
        case 'auth/user-declined':
          errorMessage = `Your registration request was declined. Please contact our support team for more information.`
          break
        case 'auth/missing-password':
          errorMessage = `Please enter your password to continue.`
          break
        case 'auth/popup-closed-by-user':
          return
      }
      reject({ status: 'error', error: errorMessage })
    }
  })
}


The browser's sessionStorage is accessible.
I am not using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO.
I am not in a storage-partitioned browser environment.
I own a custom domain
I am using firebase hosting

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any ideas on what might be causing this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
